# Adding an "all" option on categories

Tags: php, wordpress

This may seem like a basic question but I hope somebody could help me out.

I have a created a widget for a custom post type so that I could show the post types in a dynamic sidebar. In the widget, I have also created a dropdown that gets the categories to show.

My problem is that I also want to have the option to show all the categories and not just 1 category for the dropdown. Here's the code I have so far:

```
    <select id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('articleCategory'); ?>"  name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name('articleCategory'); ?>">
    <?php $arr = get_categories(); ?>
    <?php foreach($arr as $option) { ?>
    <option <?php echo $instance['articleCategory'] == $option->term_id ? 'selected="selected"' : '';?> value="<?php echo $option->term_id; ?>"><?php echo $option->name; ?></option>
    <?php } ?>
    </select>
```

Should I just use a multi-select for this and how do i go about it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this will echo out all your categories but you'll have to update the `selected` part to match your instance.

```
<option value="<?php foreach($arr as $option) {echo $option->term_id.','; };?>"><?php echo $arr; ?>All Categories</option>
```

with your full code

```
<select id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('articleCategory'); ?>"  name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name('articleCategory'); ?>">
<?php $arr = get_categories(); ?>
    <option value="<?php foreach($arr as $option) {echo $option->term_id.','; };?>"><?php echo $arr; ?>All Categories</option>
    <?php foreach($arr as $option) { ?>

    <option <?php echo $instance['articleCategory'] == $option->term_id ? 'selected="selected"' : '';?> value="<?php echo $option->term_id; ?>"><?php echo $option->name; ?></option>
    <?php } ?>
    </select>
```